# How to sort query set (or array) with more than one type of elements (classes) by common attribute using Django Python

Tags: arrays, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

I need help with creating a query set (or array) that as more than one type of elements (different classes) by a common attribute.

here are the classes:

```
class aaa(models.Model):
    fd          = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    #more attributes...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fd

class bbb(models.Model):
    fd      = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date    = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    #more attributes...

    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-timestamp"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fd
```

I want to sort all this elements by the attribute "timestamp" (that is the same in the two classes).

So far, this is what i got:

```
my_objects = (aaa.objects.all(),bbb.objects.all())
```

That creates the query set of all the elements. I prefer the query set way, if its better to use array or some other structure please let me know.

thanks!

Comment: "That creates the query set of all the elements" not true: this is a list of 2 querysets. I would look to python sort a union of the 2 querysets as list or sth like that.

Comment: You can't merge querysets from different models. At least not if they have different fields. For a possible solution hava look at https://benzidwael.wordpress.com/2015/05/16/merge-querysets-from-different-django-models/

Comment: thanks a lot @tobltobs it worked! will it be a better solution to create a class to contain this to  classes?

Comment: @GilHadad Created an answer for this solution. Regarding your question, I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the pipe to merge querysets:

```
combined = qs1 | qs2 | qs3
```

But this wont work for querysets from distinct models, at least not if they have diffferent fields. You will get an `Cannot combine queries on two different base models.` error.

A possible solution is to use `itertools.chain`, like in [this blog post](https://benzidwael.wordpress.com/2015/05/16/merge-querysets-from-different-django-models/), which i quote here for reference.

```
from itertools import chain
result_lst = list(chain(queryset1, queryset2))
```

Now, you can sort the resulting list by any common field, e.g. creation date

```
from operator import attrgetter
result_lst = sorted(
    chain(queryset1, queryset2),
    key=attrgetter('created_at'))
```